# How to draw a circle using polygon in GoogleMaps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is below code..I want a circle to be drawn using Polygon function in Maps API V3 instead of using circle function in Google maps as I have to recreate some shapes on the circumferences of the circle like here

http://textonly.in/docs/map7.html

Whether there is anyway to get the points on the circumference of the circle?

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.512158914823035,-74.12200927734375),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};

var bermudaTriangle;
var bermudaTriangle1;
var rectangle;
var citymap = {};
citymap['chicago'] = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.637839, -73.648316),
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
for (var city in citymap) {
    var populationOptions = {
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.0,
        strokeWeight: 0,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: citymap[city].center,
        radius: 39 * 1000
    };
    // Add the circle for this city to the map.
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
}
```

Comment: [Example computing points for a circular polygon](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_donut.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically it's not possible to get "the points", because a circle isn't created based on points(there would be an infinite number of points)

Possible workaround(using the geometry-library) to get "some points" to be able to create a polygon that  looks like a circle:

Use the method [`google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) in a loop with a incrementing heading:

```
  function circlePath(center, radius, points){
    var a=[],p=360/points,d=0;
    for(var i=0;i<points;++i,d+=p){
        a.push(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center,radius,d));
    }
    return a;
  }
```

The points-argument is the desired number of returned points.

The function returns an array suitable to be used as a polygon-path.

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/NLHf9/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/NLHf9/)